# Backgroundworker wait for user to fill in a filed in the GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

I have a backgroundworker and it is supposed to do 2 things.
1.Add a usercontrol to the GUI
2.read a value the user inputs in sed usercontrol and pass it to a function
What is the best way to do this?

I was thinking about having  2 event handling methods that I can pass to the DoWork event.
The first dealing with point number 1 and the second with point number 2.
Then I would do this:
1. inside worker.ProgressChanged event - the worker adds the usercontrol to the page
2. inside worker.ProgressChanged event - within a while loop the worker waits for the needed ui value to be filled in
3. inside the worker.RunWorkerCompleted event - tell the worker to perform task number 2.

Is this a correct approach?
If not what is the best method of doing this?
If this is the correct approach what is the best way for the worker to wait for the value?
Just a while loop with a sleep inside or is there a more sophisticated method?
Thank you in advance.

Edit 1: I am using WPF - XAML if this makes any difference

Comment: You should tell us _what you actually want_ to do, and not _how you think_ you should do it.

Comment: Why not use two BackgroundWorker, or completely switch to Task/Rx? BackgroundWorker is for simplest scenarios only, and Microsoft does provide much more powerful libraries for complicated cases.

Comment: Why do you want to add controls in a background worker?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think having your backgroundworker thread to wait in a loop for user input is a good idea. UI already does this and you should use that.

In my opinion, you should do this:

1. Add to backgroundworkers `DoWork` event an eventhandler that will call the function you mentioned in (2.)
2. Add an event handler to your control that will execute when user inputs something. If your control has a `TextBox` then you should add an event handler to `TextChanged` event.
3. In the event handler above, call `worker.RunWorkerAsync(textBox.Text)`

This way the processing function (2.) will be invoked only when needed and you won't waste resources waiting for the user input on two threads.

Comment: So basically you're telling me I have to use a worker for each of the operations?(2 workers in total)

Comment: @Para, if by operation you mean only invoking the function that processes user input and if you have different processing functions for each user control then yes, you should use one worker for each operation. But if the processing function is the same for every control then you only need one worker.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it in the end:

```
while(string.IsNullOrEmpty(_emailData.CaptchaCurrent))
    Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Made a variable to store the user input and had the thread wait for that particular variable to have a value.

This all goes on in a thread.